# Force re-render of vue component on click of router link

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm having an issue trying to get a component to re-render on nav click while on the same component. For example, I'm on /one -- clicking on the nav link for /one does not re-render the component which I would like it to do. Any bright ideas on how to achieve this?

router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)
import One from '../pages/One.vue'
import Two from '../pages/Two.vue'

const router = new Router({
   mode: 'history',
   routes: [
    { path: '/one', component: One, name: 'One', meta: {title: 'One'} },
    { path: '/two', component: Two, name: 'Two', meta: {title: 'Two'} },
    ]
});
export default router;
```

nav.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in nav">
        <nav-link class="nav-root-link" v-else :link="item"></nav-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

  import navLink from './navLink.vue'
  export default {
    components: { navLink },
    data () {
      return {
        groupVisible: [],
        nav: [
          { name: 'One', to: {name: 'One'}},
          { name: 'Two', to: {name: 'Two'}},
        ]
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

navLink.vue:

```
<template>
  <router-link class="nav-link" :to="link.to">
    <span class="nav-link-name">{{ link.name }}</span>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      link: {
        required: true,
        type: Object
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: try adding :key to your component. Once the :key will change the component will re render.

Comment: @RenatoManalili Do you mean add a key on the <li v-for="item in nav">, on the navLink component, or on the actual component the nav links to?

Comment: <li v-for="(item,index) in nav">
        <nav-link class="nav-root-link" v-else :link="item" :key="index"></nav-link>
 </li>

Comment: @RenatoManalili Ok, but I don't see how the key is supposed to change there. This alone does not give the desired behavior of being on the route /one and having it reload on nav click

Answer (score 0):

Wrap "One" to "OneWrap" component in which just import and use `<one v-if="isAlive">` . From this point there is many ways to achieve setting false/true to "isAlive" after menu click, which would reset component.

Answer (score -1):

Inside nav.vue just add :key

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in nav" :key="index">
        <nav-link class="nav-root-link" v-else :link="item"></nav-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is the comment @RenatoManalili gave and I responded to.